# Difference between group and users in Databricks

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, aws-databricks

In Databricks while creating a scope we can either give user level permission or can add group. What's the difference between both? Can someone from outside the workspace be included in a group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group as it name implies, groups multiple objects (users and/or service principals) under the given name.  There are two types of groups - workspace level (exist only inside workspace) and account level (exist in account and could be attached to multiple workspaces).

To be member of a group you need to be either member of workspace (for workspace-level groups) or account (for account-level).